# Not able to write ntext data into XML file from recordset

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

I am trying to run a SQL query from VBScript, obtaining the data and write it in a XML file. I have a table that contains 4 columns which contains ntext data. I am running this query individually:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml, column_name) 
FROM table 
WHERE <condition>
```

When I run it individually on the database it gives me no error and returns the value in proper XML format.

Now when I run it from VBScript, I get this error:

> C:\Users\nipaul\Desktop\New folder\ExportRuleSQLQuery.vbs(37, 2)
>   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'obj2.WriteLine'

This seems to be the line where I am trying to write the recordset into a file.

Here is the code:

```
Dim Arg, DS_var, UID_var, PWD_var, IC_var, FriendlyRuleName
Dim rstResult
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

DS_var  = Arg(0)
UID_var = Arg(1)
PWD_var = Arg(2)
IC_var  = Arg(3)
FriendlyRuleName = Arg(4)

Set obj  = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set obj1 = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set obj2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Users\nipaul\Desktop\filename.xml", 2, True)

Dim dbquery
Dbquery = "SELECT CONVERT(xml, column) FROM table WHERE FriendlyName='" & FriendlyRuleName & "'"

obj.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=" & DS_var & ";UserId=" & UID_var & ";Password=" & PWD_var & ";Initial Catalog= " & IC_var & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;DataTypeCompatibility=80"

obj1.Open dbquery, obj

'While obj1.EOF = False
'    obj2.Writeline obj1
'    obj1.MoveNext
'Wend
'obj1.Save "C:\Users\nipaul\Desktop\Rule.xml", adPersistXML
Do Until obj1.EOF
    rstResult = obj1
    obj2.WriteLine rstResult
    rstUsers.MoveNext
Loop
obj2.Close
Set obj2 = Nothing
obj1.Close
obj.Close
Set obj1 = Nothing
Set obj  = Nothing
Set Arg  = Nothing
```

I want the output of the query in that XML file.

```
<note> 
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: the column is of ntext type in database.

Comment: The ntext datatype has been deprecated for almost 15 years now. Maybe time to update your datatypes. Also, you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. My friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this that is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would try explicitly saying which field you're writing to file

```vb
rstResult = obj1.Fields(0).Value ' or rstResult = obj1(0) might work because of default properties
```

It might also be worth removing the conversion to XML, because in the end all you're doing is writing text to a text file.